# Flutter consulta de horarios disponibles y no disponibles

Tags: flutter

Soy nueva en flutter, estoy desarrollando una app para unos doctores, me he trabado mucho en un problema, he intentado varias cosas pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo, en la siguiente imagen se muestra el calendario ahí hago peticiones http a un servidor para que me traiga la información, acerca de los horarios que tienen los doctores de sus citas, lo que me pidieron hacer es que ahí mismo muestre las horas disponibles que quedan:

Aquí muestro los horarios que están ocupados:

[image: aqui muestro los horarios que están ocupados]

---

En esta imagen es lo que desean que ponga, para mostrar los horarios disponibles:

[image: en esta imagen es lo que desean que ponga, para mostrar los horarios disponibles]

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? no he encontrado información acerca de como añadir los cards ya que todo lo pongo en un listviewbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

no se como esta construido la respuesta de tu backend pero me imagino que debe ser como lo muestro a continuación, deberías tener un campo que controle el estado de cada horario disponible y no disponible ,cuando listas estos horarios deberías buscar este campo y realizar una validación para mostrar en rojo u otra alarma que te indique el estado de la misma así como te muestro en el widget card.

supuesta respuesta backend:

```
{
  "idhorario":1,
  "nombre":"horario1",
   "fecha":"04/09/2021",
  "hora":"8:00 a 8:30",
  "disponible": true     
}
{
  "idhorario":2,
  "nombre":"horario2",
"fecha":"04/09/2021",
  "hora":"9:00 a 9:30",
  "disponible": false    
}
{
  "idhorario":1,
  "nombre":"horario1",
"fecha":"04/09/2021",
  "hora":"10:00 a 10:30",
  "disponible":false     
}
```

widget card :

```
 ListView.builder( 
.
.
.
   Card(
   child: Column(
    children: [
    Text(tumodelo.hora)
   Text(tumodelo.disponible==true?'HORARIO DISPONIBLE':'HORARIO NO DISPONIBLE')
      ],
      ),
   )
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero lo que pasa que realmente no tengo un back como tal, solo hago archivos de php para hacer este tipo de consulta, ya que es lo único que cuento de la empresa, en los archivos php me trae las consultas de horarios que no están disponibles, solo eso, ya que eso esta ya configurado, no puedo modificar nada ya de lo que esta hecho, por ejemplo poner un nuevo campo el estado de cada horario :(